# Calculating the force produced by acoustic levitation

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I was reading some articles about acoustic levitation and I was wondering whether it is possible to lift a 100 kips load off the ground for about 0.5-1 inches with that. If it is, how should I calculate how much energy I need to deliver to a ultrasound speaker and effectively concentrate with a lens that can be used to produce such lift on an object.

I am not very familiar with this subject, so forgive me if I am asking some pretty dum question here. Thanks!!

Edit - Somebody apparently downvoted the question without saying why, I don't exactly know why. But I thought I should put some additional info to help people understand what I am referring to. Showing some "effort".... It is such a new field that there are not a lot of articles on how you calculate something like this and what is realistic.

1. [Acoustic levitation made simple](https://phys.org/news/2015-01-acoustic-levitation-simple.html)
2. [Researchers demonstrate acoustic levitation of a large sphere](https://phys.org/news/2016-08-acoustic-levitation-large-sphere.html)

Comment: I don't know why people would down vote without a proper explanation... Where did that come from???

Comment: +1, doesn't seem to be an unreasonable question to me.  It is an obscure area of research after all.

Comment: you should realize this is an international forum and most folks wont know what a "kip" is.  ( He wants to acoustically lift 45 metric tons )

Comment: ... the fact that levitating a styrofoam ball warranted a paper in Applied Physics Letters should give a clue about whats feasable...

Comment: Erm, but that device in there is really small. Can we just make a super size replica and lift like a much heavier object as long as it is a small distance, like 1 inch? (And I don't think kips is unreasonable... It is a unit of measure, albeit not a familiar form that you use all the time. For your reference, I was raised in Asia and I have no issues with the use of either. 100kips = 444kN for reference...)